# Getting error regarding slice during Karma/AngularJS unit test config

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

```
$ karma init configs/karma.conf.js
>
readline.js:507
  this.line = this.line.slice(this.cursor);
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined
    at Interface._deleteLineLeft (readline.js:507:25)
    at suggestNextOption         (C:\Users\DEVUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:165:9)
at nextQuestion (C:\Users\DEVUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:231:12)
at process (C:\Users\DEVUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:246:10)
at Object.exports.init (C:\Users\DEVUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:348:6)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DEVUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\bin\karma:26:37)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I am getting this error when trying to run karma init configs/karma.conf.js

I have all of this running under Windows 7 x64

I am following this guide: https://coderwall.com/p/xz-qcg

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I've gotten almost exactly the same error.  I had nodejs installed, I installed the karma package, and ran "karma init". The only differences are that it was on line 494 of readline.js, and it said "StateMachine.suggestNextOption" instead of "suggestNextOption".  I'm on Win7x32.

Comment: Just so it's clear, once I upgraded node to the latest (0.10.18), my "karma init" now produces a stack trace that is even closer to what you reported, so that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070777/get-error-with-line-slice-on-karma-init), but I was running this in Cygwin.  I don't know if you were.

I first uninstalled and reinstalled nodejs.

When I brought up the rxvt window again to try installing karma, it failed with this:

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 4: $'\r': command not found
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 5: `case `uname` in
```

This is apparently because of my using it in Cygwin, although I don't know why I didn't get this error before. The following talks about this: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3710 .

So, I then just opened up a plain "cmd" window, and I found that the package install completed, and "karma init" worked well enough to ask me the first "init" question, so I imagine this is resolved.