# Get error with "line.slice()" on "karma init"

Tags: javascript, node.js, karma-runner

I was started to read "Developing an AngularJS Edge", and I wanted to set up the various frameworks in use.

The book uses nodejs and karma, along with several other frameworks.

I'm on Win7x32.

I just upgraded my nodejs to the latest, v0.10.18 .

I installed the Karma package with "npm install -g karma".  This appeared to complete successfully.

I then ran "karma init", which did this:

```
    % karma init
> 
readline.js:507
  this.line = this.line.slice(this.cursor);
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'slice' of undefined
    at Interface._deleteLineLeft (readline.js:507:25)
    at suggestNextOption (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:167:9)
    at nextQuestion (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:235:12)
    at process (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:250:10)
    at Object.exports.init (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\lib\init.js:352:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\bin\karma:25:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Note that this error is virtually identical to the stack trace reported by [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511860/getting-error-regarding-slice-during-karma-angularjs-unit-test-config) a month ago, but that report has received no response.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with node 0.10.18, karma 0.10.2 on Windows 7 Ultimate (both 32 and 64 bit)

Comment: Are there any additional diagnostics I can produce that might provide more meaningful information?

Comment: Did you install using the package from nodejs.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error with running npm in Cygwin seems to be a known issue with npm. You can use the work around mentioned here,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22436199/2390020

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about this question.  I discovered this workaround quite a while ago.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you're using the Git Bash terminal, MinTTY, which doesn't have full support for TTY.

You have 4 options to fix the problem:

1. Use CMD terminal with the **Windows shell** (the default Windows console)
2. Use CMD terminal with the **Bash shell** (execute `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i` in cmd terminal)
3. Use Powershell (an alternative terminal typically installed by default in Windows environments)
4. Use an alternative terminal (or develop a new one :stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye: )

If you just need execute isolated interactive commands like `karma init`, I recommend **option 1** for it and then come back to Git Bash. However I would give a try to Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue.try this

node node_modules/karma/bin/karma init

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with MINGW64.

Runs properly on default command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

One other likely relevant point that I failed to mention is that I was running these commands from a Cygwin rxvt window.

I just tried completely uninstalling nodejs and reinstalling it.

When I brought up the rxvt window again and ran "npm install -g karma", it failed with the following:

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 4: $'\r': command not found
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 5: `case `uname` in
```

That led me to search for that error on the web, and I found this [thread](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3710), which implies that it simply doesn't support Cygwin (unfortunate, but not a huge problem).

When I then brought up a plain, ugly, unfriendly "cmd" window, both the karma installation and "karma init" completed successfully (or at least it gave me the first question in the "init" process).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I was using the git bash terminal in windows. When I ran the command in a cmd window it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in github shell command window. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the `karma` file it's just a node script, so an alternative way of executing it would be:

```
node karma init
```

This worked for me in the MINGW64/git bash shell